Не работает команда для Discord бота на Python
При запуске тупо ничего не делает, по идее эта команда должна читать сообщения в канале для запроса с позывными, искать там текст "3.", копировать текст после "3." (пример:

@Pro

Pro9051_10

"Alpha-00" | Pro9051_10

@leader )
после чего команда должна ждать пока человек с ролью "Leader" ID которой указан в самом начале кода поставит под сообщение эмодзи ✅, после чего она должна менять ник отправителю сообщения например на "Alpha-00" | Pro9051_10, при этом убирая пользователю старый ник и не копируя 4 пункт.
Говорю сразу, возможно в коде нет ошибок, я забыл добавить проверку, код должен проверять старые сообщения, искать есть ли под ними ✅, при этом от лидера, после чего проверять ник пользователя, смотреть изменён ли он, смотреть дату сообщения, если ему более 5 дней не менять пользователю ник, если же у пользователя ещё не стоит ник который он  запрашивал, под сообщением стоит ✅ от пользователя с ролью "Leader" и сообщению меньше 5 дней делать всё выше перечисленное, то есть копировать текст после "3.", не трогая "4.", убирать пользователю старый ник и ставить новый.
Так же там стоит fonity_number, то есть фигня которая меняет скопированному позывному шрифт, то есть а = , А =  и тп, меняя ник допустим на "-" | _.
Вот сам код:


    allowed_channels = [1230204417492385908]  # замените на реальный ID канала
    YOUR_LEADER_ROLE_ID = 1215869495168467029  # замените на реальный ID роли Leader

    # Функция для конвертации текста в желаемый шрифт
    async def fontify_string(input_string):
        font_map = {'a': '', 'b': '', 'c': '', 'd': '', 'e': '',
            'f': '', 'g': '', 'h': '', 'i': '', 'j': '',
            'k': '', 'l': '', 'm': '', 'n': '', 'o': '',
            'p': '', 'q': '', 'r': '', 's': '', 't': '',
            'u': '', 'v': '', 'w': '', 'x': '', 'y': '',
            'z': '',
            'A': '', 'B': '', 'C': '', 'D': '', 'E': '',
            'F': '', 'G': '', 'H': '', 'I': '', 'J': '',
            'K': '', 'L': '', 'M': '', 'N': '', 'O': '',
            'P': '', 'Q': '', 'R': '', 'S': '', 'T': '',
            'U': '', 'V': '', 'W': '', 'X': '', 'Y': '',
            'Z': ''}
        converted_string = ''
        for char in input_string:
            if char.lower() in font_map:
                converted_char = font_map[char.lower()]
                if char.isupper():
                    converted_char = converted_char.upper()
                converted_string += converted_char
            else:
                converted_string += char
        return converted_string

    @bot.event
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
        if str(payload.emoji) == '✅':
            channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            if message.channel.id in allowed_channels and "3." in message.content:
                leader_role = message.guild.get_role(YOUR_LEADER_ROLE_ID)
                user = message.author
                if leader_role in user.roles:
                    content_parts = message.content.split('3.')
                    text_after_3 = content_parts[1].split('4.')[0].strip()
                    nickname = await fontify_string(text_after_3)
                    if nickname != user.display_name:
                        try:
                            await user.edit(nick=nickname)
                        except discord.Forbidden as e:
                            print(f"Не удалось изменить ник пользователя: {e}")

    @tasks.loop(seconds=60)
    async def check_reactions():
        await bot.wait_until_ready()  # Ждем, пока бот будет готов
        while not bot.is_closed():  # Проверяем, что бот не закрыт
            for channel_id in allowed_channels:  # Перебираем разрешенные каналы
                channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
                if channel:  # Убеждаемся, что канал найден
                    async for message in channel.history(limit=10):  # Перебираем последние 10 сообщений в канале
                        for reaction in message.reactions:  # Перебираем реакции на сообщение
                            if str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':  # Проверяем реакцию
                                users = []
                                async for user in reaction.users():
                                    users.append(user)
                                bot_user = discord.utils.get(users, id=bot.user.id)  # Ищем своего бота в списке пользователей
                                if bot_user:  # Проверяем, что бот найден
                                    payload = discord.RawReactionActionEvent(  # Создаем объект RawReactionActionEvent
                                        data={
                                            'user_id': bot_user.id,
                                            'message_id': message.id,
                                            'channel_id': channel.id,
                                            'emoji': '✅',
                                            'event_type': discord.RawReactionActionEvent.REACTION_ADD,
                                        })
                                    await bot.on_raw_reaction_add(payload)  # Вызываем on_raw_reaction_add с объектом payload
                                    break  # Выходим из цикла реакций, так как уже обнаружена нужная реакция
            await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Ждем 60 секунд перед повторной проверкой






Добро пожаловать на сайт, user591353! ознакомьтесь пожалуйста со справкой как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
